# Is it possible to enter assembler code into MPLAB to find out the value of the machine code in WREG?

Tags: assembly, pic, mplab

I have an exam in august in microcomputers. Some of the questions involve calculating the binary value of the machine code in WREG. You need to find out the value of WREG after some assembler instructions. Is it possible in some way to use MPLAB X, enter the code and let it calculate the value for me as a hindsight?

As an example, I would like to know what the value of WREG is after this code, by using MPLAB X:

```
MAIN    CLRF    WREG
    INCF    WREG
    XORLW   0XFE
    ADDLW   0X01
    COMF    WREG
    ANDLW   0x33
```

How do I do it? Thanks

Comment: There are several solutions: 1) Memorize the PIC assembly language instructions and how they work so you can do this in your own head. 2) Learn to use MPLABX to build assembly language source code. 3) Ask a question like: Can anyone on StackOverflow create an MPLABX assembly language project for a PIC18Fxxxxx device so I can learn to use the MPLABX simulator.

Comment: You could enter WREG to your Variables list.

Comment: Thank you ive solved it

Comment: How did you solved it? This a forum and maybe someone else find your answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing the code into MPLABX and breakpoint every line. I tracked variables such as WREG and saw how they changed throughout the running of the program. That way I knew the value of WREG in the end and  why it got the value it did.

Comment: You don't need a breakpoint on every line. Just single step through the code and have a look at WREG in the variables list.